# Issue with deserializing differing data

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Json.net JsonConvert to deserialize some JSON from a rest API, in this fashion:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
          using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

This is working great, expect for when trying to obtain a specific set of data, which when eserialized generates this error:

```
Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path
```

I have narrowed down the issue to the API returning data in an incorrect format for some entries. So most of the data coming back looks like this:

```
   Income: {
    currency: {
        GBP: "48",
        USD: "32",
        EUR: "40"
    }
},
```

However, in some cases, it is returning:

```
income: {
    currency: {
        GBP: {
        GBP: "0",
        USD: "0",
        EUR: "0"
    },
    USD: {
        GBP: "0",
        USD: "0",
        EUR: "0"
    },
    EUR: {
        GBP: "0",
        USD: "0",
    EUR: "0"
    }
}
```

For the short term, there is nothing I can do to get the API fixed, so I need to handle this somehow, but I'm relatively new to using Json.net, so i'm not sure of the best way to do so. Any advice is appreciated.

The class structure I am trying to deserialise into is pretty simple:

```
  public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Income> Income_list { get; set; }

    }

 public class Income
    {
        public Currency currency { get; set; }

    }

    public class Currency
    {
        public string GBP { get; set; }
        public string USD { get; set; }
        public string EUR { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `RootObject`?

Comment: @nick_w code posted, the class for currency is obviously intended for the data returned for most API requests.

Comment: That second JSON example appears to be invalid (probably explains the error you got). What sort of output would you like it transformed into? Also, shouldn't the `Income` object be an array in the JSON rather than an object literal?

Comment: @nick_w The incorrect JSON appears to always return 0 anyway, so I either want to transform it into the correct format, with zeros for values, or if that's not doable, even just ignoring it and having a null value would be better.

Comment: So what's the goal of transforming the data? If invalid JSON just has zeros for the currency values anyway, couldn't you just catch the parsing exception and return a new `Income` with its `Currency` initialised to contain zeros?

Comment: A very good point, I've done that and that's done the job.

Comment: Did it? That's good to hear. Shall I post it as an answer?

Comment: go for it and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the invalid JSON has zeros for the currency values anyway, it is probably much easier to simply catch the JSON deserialization exception and return a new `Income` object with its `Currency` object initialised to be all zeros.